# How to check if word in ArrayList is substring of name in file, then increment the count of that word?

Tags: java, arraylist

So if I'm trying to read a recipe file, the file is supposed to find words that match with the words on my ArrayList and if there is a match, the count of that word gets incremented. Here is what I have so far but I am stuck on what I should do in the loop.

```
public class Main {
    private Scanner inp = new Scanner( System.in);
    private ArrayList<String> foodList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private int ingredientCount = 0;

    public A1() {
        foodList.add("baking powder");
        foodList.add("baking soda");
        foodList.add("cheese");
        foodList.add("broth");
        foodList.add("tomato paste");
        foodList.add("tomato");
        foodList.add("flour");
        foodList.add("egg");
        foodList.add("garlic");
        foodList.add("cheese");
        foodList.add("rice");
        foodList.add("onion");
        foodList.add("salt");
        foodList.add("pepper");
        foodList.add("vinegar");
        foodList.add("carrot");
        foodList.add("sweet potato");
        foodList.add("potato");
        foodList.add("cream");
        foodList.add("milk");
        foodList.add("bean");
        foodList.add("green bean");
        foodList.add("beef");
        foodList.add("chicken");
        foodList.add("cumin");
        foodList.add("basil");
        foodList.add("oregano");
        foodList.add("oil");
        foodList.add("fish");
    }

    private void readFile() {
        while (inp.hasNext()) {
            String nextLine = inp.next().toLowerCase();

            if (nextLine.contains(foodList())) { 
                totalwordcount++; //This is the part I'm stuck on. How do I only 
                        //incriment that food item from the list?
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Do you want to count the number of all ingredients (like 1 tomato + 2 salt = 3 ingredients), or you you want to keep track of the individual ingredients? (like 1 tomato + 2 salt, without merging them)

Comment: I want to keep track of the individual ingredients.

Comment: Use a `HashMap<String, int>` for this sort of thing--you want to map each word with a count of the occurrences.

Comment: Could not have said better than @ggorlen.

Comment: For this one I can't use a HashMap, I have to do it through a loop from the ArrayList somehow.

Comment: but you want count of each ingirdient that why you need hashmap

Comment: Use your `ArrayList` values as a key to your `HashMap<String, int>` and increment the value if the key if found. Plenty of examples online available.

Comment: So, keeping the total for each ingredient in a `Map` (as suggested by @ggorlen) is not allowed?

Comment: No it isn't for my assignment. I also didn't learn how to use Hash Maps yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not permitted to use a `Map<String, Integer>` to keep the counts you could just use an array:

```
private Scanner inp = new Scanner( System.in);
private ArrayList<String> foodList = new ArrayList<String>();
private int[] ingredientCount;

public A1() {
    foodList.add("baking powder");
    foodList.add("baking soda");
    // ...
    foodList.add("oil");
    foodList.add("fish");

    ingredientCount = new int[foodList.size()];
}

private void readFile() {
  while (inp.hasNext()) {
      String nextLine = inp.next().toLowerCase();

      for(int i=0; i<foodList.size(); i++)
      {
        if (nextLine.contains(foodList.get(i))) { 
          ingredientCount[i] += 1;
        }
      }
  }

  for(int i=0; i<foodList.size(); i++)
  {
    System.out.printf("%s occured %d time(s)\n", foodList.get(i), ingredientCount[i]);
  }
}
```